# My images aren't loading after adding update_option('upload_url_path', '')

Tags: images, themes, url-rewriting, media

I tried using update_option('upload_url_path', '/product_large') to change the url of my images. After updating the functions.php my images aren't loading in my site. Any possible solution? Thanks!

Comment: Changing the upload path doesn't move existing files. Try uploading a new one and verify that it lands where you expected, and then you can set up redirects or take the time to move all the existing images.